# Looking to kill frmweb processes with no jobs

Tags: linux, script, process, kill, oracle-linux

So I am trying to figure out a way to kill Oracle frmweb processes that are doing nothing when load begins to get too high.

So far, I have found this command:

`ps -elf | head -1; ps -elf | awk '{if ($5 == 1 && $3 == "oracle" && $15 == "frmweb") {print $0}}' | head`

This command in theory should show me orphaned processes, but I was wondering if there was a way to automate all of this if the load is over 4.00 for 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

From [Perform action based on load avg](https://serverfault.com/questions/422915/perform-action-based-on-load-avg) it appears that [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) will do what you are asking.

You'll want to follow the steps at [Resource Testing](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#resource_testing) and use the LOADAVG(5min)

As an example:

```
 if loadavg(5min) is greater than 4.00 for 2 cycles then exec '/usr/local/bin/frmwebkill.sh'
```

Where frmwebkill runs the command you specified to find orphans and then kills the found processes.

Comment: Thanks, I talked to the powers that be but they want to try something with bash first. Do you know of any way to accomplish this without monit?